# Extract nested JSON file into a dataframe - python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I am attempting to transform the JSON into a dataframe of just the price information. I understand the API process and how to get the JSON, but then the data I need to put into a dataframe are a series of dictionaries that are nested in a list, which is nested in a dictionary which is nested in another dictionary which is further nested in another dictionary. I would like to get the dataframe to have the columns be the keys of the prices list. I am fairly new to Python, so this is quite challenging. Not sure if it is even possible - deep nestlings.

I have provided my yahoofinancials API code and snippet of the JSON output variables.  Thanks for any help.

The printed values look like this, and I am trying to get to the prices portion with all the data (there are many more instances but this is to show where the prices is located in the JSON).

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
raw_data = YahooFinancials('CL=F')
raw_data = raw_data.get_historical_price_data("2017-07-23", "2019-02-13", "weekly")
print(raw_data.values())

dict_values([{'eventsData': {}, 'firstTradeDate': {'formatted_date': '2018-07-23', 'date': 1532318400}, 'currency': 'USD', 'instrumentType': 'FUTURE', 'timeZone': {'gmtOffset': -18000}, 'prices': [{'date': 1532318400, 'high': 69.91999816894531, 'low': 0.0, 'open': 69.19000244140625, 'close': 68.94000244140625, 'volume': 1060185822, 'adjclose': 68.94000244140625, 'formatted_date': '2018-07-23'}, {'date': 1532923200, 'high': 70.43000030517578, 'low': 66.91999816894531, 'open': 68.87000274658203, 'close': 68.5999984741211, 'volume': 1108305118, 'adjclose': 68.5999984741211, 'formatted_date': '2018-07-30'}
```

Would like to have all the 'prices' data (date, high, low, open, close, volume, adjclose, formatted_date) put into a data frame that I can then manipulate with Pandas and NumPy.

Comment: Try using [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import pandas as pd

raw_data = YahooFinancials('CL=F')
raw_data = raw_data.get_historical_price_data("2017-07-23", "2019-02-13", "weekly")
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data['CL=F']['prices'])
```